# How run dasdardly with GitHub Actions?

Tags: docker, yaml, github-actions

I've not really used GitHub for much and I'm trying to use dastardly to do a pen test on my web servers.  This is the only thing I want to do so I thought GitHub Actions would be the simplest... So far, that hasn't been the case.

I've installed Docker, downloaded the files for using dastardly in GitHub Actions (Dockerfile, action.yml), tried to use: docker compose build, docker compose up, but it says it can't find the configuration file on both commands.  I've not seen anything about a config file in the dastardly examples.

I've also seen people ask if you can run Github actions locally.  I don't think that matters in my needs but have no clue there either. But I'm using yaml and it looks like that's a recent change.

Can anyone point me to a link or describe what I need to do from the beginning to use dastardly?

EDIT:
I've been trying to make progress but still no luck.  I have the following files in a github repository:

Dasterdly.yml

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main # Specify the branch where changes trigger the workflow
jobs:
  scan:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest # Specify the runner for the job

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
  # Add your Dastardly scan steps here
  - name: 'Run Dastardly Scan Action'
    uses: ./.github/workflows/actions.yml@v2
    with:
        target-url: 'https://myserver.net'
        output-filename: 'dastardly-report.xml'
        
  # Example step to print workspace contents for debugging
  - name: List workspace contents
    run: ls /github/workspace
```

actions.yml

```
name: 'Dastardly Scan Action'
description: 'Runs a Dastardly scan against a target site'
inputs:
  target-url:
    description: 'https://velocedge.learn.net'
    required: true
  output-filename:
    description: 'The filename used for the scan report. This filepath relates to the dastardly container, and will exist in the github workspace (/github/workspace)'
    required: false
    default: dastardly-report.xml
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
  env:
    BURP_START_URL: $${{ inputs.target-url }}
    BURP_REPORT_FILE_PATH: /github/workspace/$${{ inputs.output-filename }}
branding:
  icon: 'activity'
  color: 'green'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/portswigger/dastardly:latest
USER root
```

I get two errors. First error:

```
Error: .github#L1
No event triggers defined in `on`
```

But I have on: push: branches: -main... so not sure what wrong with that.  Second error:

```
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/initial-repository/initial-repository/.github/workflows/actions.yml@v2'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

I didn't forget to run actions/checkout, I just don't know how.